# JQuery or Javascript, how to get paragraph contenteditable plane text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable

I have a paragraph `<p>` with `contenteditable="true"` and it's work fine with every option I've create, like BOLD, ITALIC, BGCOLOR, ...

---

I type space in my contenteditable paragraph and When I comparing contents of that contenteditable paragraph with string by following code it returns me false !

```
console.log($('p[contenteditable="true"]').text()==" ");
// return false
console.log($('p[contenteditable="true"]').text());
// return " " char Code of this space is 160
```

It's so weird ! why it's happening?
and I've tried above code with `.textContent` and SAME RESULT happened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested what you posted and it is working. See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zet44/4/)

HTML:

```
<p contenteditable="true"> </p>
```

Javascript:

```
console.log(jQuery('p[contenteditable="true"]').text());
console.log(jQuery('p[contenteditable="true"]').text() == ' ');
console.log(jQuery('p[contenteditable="true"]').text().charCodeAt(0));
```

Returns:

```
" "
true
32
```

Please check that you are actually inputting a space (Char code 32) and not a different character.

Solution:

```
if(jQuery('p[contenteditable="true"]').text().charCodeAt(0) == 160){
    console.log('Space!');
}
```

Please see: [HTML Char Code](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm)

Comment: no! you write space in html codes! I wrote that space in paragraph by contenteditable wysiwyg! and Char code of my space is **160** !

Comment: Thats exactly my point. In your javascript you are matching against a standard space(char code 32) but wysiwyg is adding a &nbsp; (char code 160).

Comment: Thanks for solution ! let me test it